# Changing Wordpress function

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I'm using a Wordpress function to enter the word 'and' before the last term in calling a term list, like this:

```
function TermList($taxonomy = 'markup') {
    global $post;
    $term_list = '';
    $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, $taxonomy);
    $n = 1;
    if ($terms) {
        foreach($terms as $term) {
            if ($n < count($terms)) {
                $term_list .= $term->name . ', ';
            } else {
                $term_list = rtrim($term_list, ', ') .  ' and ' . $term->name;
            }
            ++$n;
        }
    }

    $term_list = rtrim($term_list, ', ');

    return $term_list;
}
```

I want to change this function so it only displays 5 terms and chooses those 5 terms randomly from all available terms. I don't know where to start. Who can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

**Using array_rand**

You could use `array_rand` in php to select a random element from an array, here is the [official documentation from php.net](https://www.php.net/array_rand)

and your code will be something like:

```
for($i=0 ; $i<5 ; $i++){
    $term_list .=  $terms [array_rand($terms )] . ', ';
}
$term_list = rtrim($term_list, ', ');

// replace the last comma with 'and'
$portion = strrchr($term_list , ',');
$term_list = str_replace($portion, (" and" . substr($portion, 1, -1)), $term_list );
```

**Using shuffle and array_slice**

Another solution to pick up random elements from an array could be using `shuffle` to randomly shuffle the elements of an array and then using `array_slice` [to pick up certain elements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php).

Here is an example of code:

```
shuffle($terms );
print_r(array_slice($terms , 0, 3));
```